# Redirect output to txt file on multiple lines

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>  

int main()   
{   
  int n, count = 1;   
  float x, average, sum = 0;   
  printf("How many numbers do you wish to test: ");  
  scanf ("%d",&n);   
  while (count <= n)   
     {   
      printf ("Enter number #%d: ",count);   
      scanf("%f", &x);   
      sum += x;   
      ++count;   
     }   
    average = sum/n;   
    printf("\nThe Average is: %.2f\n", average);   
}
```

This program asks the user for a certain amount of numbers to be entered and then calculates the average of those numbers. I then use a input.txt file to redirect the input and direct to an output.txt file. So using the command

> ./main < input.txt > output.txt

My question is, how do I make it so when the output is redirected, the output appears on multiple lines instead of all in one single line. For example, when I run the command and look at my output.txt file it looks like this:

> How many numbers do you wish to test: Enter number #1: Enter number
> #2: Enter number #3: Enter number #4: Enter number #5: The Average is: 6.00

Is there a way to make it look like this instead:

> How many numbers do you wish to test:
> Enter number #1:
> Enter number #2:
> Enter number #3:
> Enter number #4:
> Enter number #5:
> The Average is: 6.00

Comment: Use line breaks `"\n"` to represent new lines in a string. You can just print them like you would any other text.

Comment: This has nothing to do with bash, you'd have the same problem if you were using some other method to redirect the output.

Comment: How come the `The Average is: 6.00` is on the same line as rest of the input prompts. Run it without `> output.txt` and modify `stdout` prints to your liking & then redirect. Print the inputs too, it makes more sense having them together.

Comment: `printf ("\nEnter number #%d: ",count);` It will double-space on the terminal, but does the job for redirection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only line break you output is at the very end of your code. If you want line breaks in the output, output them wherever you want them, just as you did in the last line of code.